# Replace value between tag in PHP

Tags: php, regex

I have a string that contains the following text:

```
Id: {id}
Status: {status}
Priority: {prio}
```

I would like to replace **{id}**, **{status}** and **{prio}** with its respective value.

For example:

```
{i} = '1'
{status} = 'New'
{prio}: 'Low'
```

How to do that in PHP?

Comment: `preg_match_callback` + `~\{([^\}]+)\}~`

Comment: Respective value from the variable of the same name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`preg_replace_callback`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php); The return value of the callback function is used as replacement string.

```
$data = array(
    'id' => '1',
    'status' => 'New',
    'prio' => 'Low',
);

$str = 'Id: {id}
Status: {status}
Priority: {prio}';

$str = preg_replace_callback('/{(\w+)}/', function($match) use($data) {
    return $data[$match[1]];
}, $str);

echo($str);
```

output:

```
Id: 1
Status: New
Priority: Low
```

Answer (score 2):

See **[strtr](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtr.php)** (without regex)

```
$trans = array(
    '{id}'     => '1', 
    '{status}' => 'New',
    '{prio}'   => 'Low'     
);

echo strtr($text, $trans);
```